# signtool results corrupted setup.exe

Tags: installation, code-signing, signtool

I try to sign my setup.exe like this:
signtool sign /a setup.exe
The signing is succeeded, verified OK, but when I start the setup, it recognises that the content changed, and it sais: "The setup is corrupted...". I tried this with two different install maker (Smart Installer, Actual Installer).

Edit: With Actual Installer, there is a sollution: "To avoid this issue, please go to General-Graphics page and uncheck 'Custom Icon' checkbox."

Comment: Perhaps the setup file has a signature which is verified when launched. The digital signing process modifies this signature and the file is considered corrupted. Does the setup authoring tool you are using have a digital signature feature? If it does, try using that instead of a command line.

Comment: It would help if you told us which install makers you used...

Comment: Cosmin Pirvu: I agree with you, but int this case the problem should be very frequent for everybody, but I didn't found anybody with the same problem.

Comment: Are you attempting to re-sign a file that has been signed already? You only get one bite of the cherry with Authenticode - if you modify a file that has been signed you can't fix the signature by re-signing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, S.I.M. seems to do some checksum not only in the compressed data, but in whole file, so it can't be signed, include the last version v5.0.4, is unable to be signed. The developers of that tool don't seems to care about it, last update year 2011, and they don't answer support communications from licensed customer asking about this topic, I thinks only the sell system works well because is automatic, seems like a project that is on auto-pilot, no humans behind.

So buying S.I.M. is to get stuck with no sign.